# Nova sala de chat - JavaScript

Tags: debate, chat

As linguagens em que estou mais em casa são JavaScript (e por consequência Node.js). Numa tentativa de criar um novo espaço para falar de JavaScript criei a [sala de chat JavaScript.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25038/javascript)

No SOen há uma sala de JavaScript bem ativa e onde se trocam ideias e novidades sobre a linguagem e gostava de ter algo assim, aqui, convosco.

Não para criar uma sala como o [Estouro de Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para um subgrupo mas sim uma sala mais focada em trocar experiência sobre a linguagem em foco e sem divagar demais no "bate-papo" e foco das conversas. Esta sala não deve servir para como regra tirar dúvidas que deviam ser perguntas úteis para a comunidade, mas sim como um complemento.

Enfim, à parte destas expectativas que são minhas e não vos quero/posso forçar, o que acham da ideia de ter esta nova sala?

E ainda mais importante, de que maneira podíamos dinamizar este espaço?

Eu tomei a iniciativa de colocar links como *starred* para servirem de marcador a artigos/recursos interessantes. Mas mais ideias são muito bem vindas!

Comment: +1 pela iniciativa.

Comment: +1, estou lá. Eu acho que as salas de chat seriam bem mais movimentadas se não ficassem escondidas no rodapé do site.

Comment: A propósito, nada mal uma medalha chamada *Chat Hunter* com descrição: "*encontrou e visitou o chat pelo menos uma vez*".

Comment: Mais uma medalha não cairia mal. =D

Comment: Acho que poderia ter uma sala para as cinco linguagens mais usadas no site.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez uma sala para cada uma das cinco ou uma sala para as cinso juntas?

Comment: @Sergio Uma pra cada. Note que são poucos os usuários que respondem todas as tags. A maioria responde apenas um grupo de tags.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pois perguntei só para clarificar. Acho boa ideia!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Só criar uma e divulgar aqui!

Comment: @Gabe Sim, senhor!

Comment: Aproveitando o chat alguem poderia me ajudar nessa pergunta?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72726/editar-dados-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment149650_72726

Comment: Estou começando com NodeJs e gostando muito, porem enrosquei na parte de editar os dados do banco no meu Crud kk

Comment: @Techies coloca a pergunta no chat em vez de aqui. Já a tinha visto, dei `+1` e quero ajudar mas tou apertado de tempo. Espero conseguir em breve.

Comment: Beleza, vou colocar lá e tentar participar bastante. Obrigado