# Nova Sala de Chat - C#, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, EF, etc

Tags: debate, chat

[O @Sergio criou um chat apenas de JavaScript](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4032/nova-sala-de-chat-javascript), então [criei uma sala que reúne várias tecnologias em comum, usadas para montar aplicações com base no C#](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc).

Analogamente, a ideia é a gente usar este espaço para conversar sobre práticas de programação. Várias pessoas que estão começando procuram o site pra aprender a programar usando essas tecnologias, e o que normalmente ocorre é uma coisa meio caótica: as perguntas criadas respondem a coisas meio específicas, e é só depois de alguns dias (por experiência, algumas semanas) que as pessoas aprendem direitinho o que é preciso ser feito pra criar um bom sistema, onde e como encontrar bons materiais de referência, e assim por diante.

A ideia da sala é deixar a coisa um pouco mais dinâmica e prática. O objetivo é uma troca mais direcionada de informações, com links para exemplos, compartilhamento de GitHub, e assim por diante. Um verdadeiro [*Coding Craft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_craftsmanship), se é que se pode chamar assim.

Gostaria de saber, aliás, se vocês acham uma boa ideia colocar o link do chat dentro do Wiki dessas tags. Pra novos usuários, com certeza vou indicar a sala para um ponto de partida de tutoriais e onde buscar ajuda.

Comment: Ótima iniciativa. Só acho que a reputação para participar no chat poderia ser menor, os mais novatos vão acabar não se beneficiando dessa ferramenta.

Comment: @Math Sim, eu abaixaria pra 6 de reputação. Se um novato faz uma pergunta e é algo pertinente, um *upvote* de pergunta já seria suficiente pra entrar no chat.