# Nova sala X, nova sala Y... pra quê mesmo?

Tags: debate, chat

Por favor antes de atirarem pedras em mim, leiam :)

Eu entendi o motivo das salas, é ajudar pessoas "mais novas", discutir abertamente sobre os assuntos sem precisar de respostas "definitivas".

No entanto, vou dizer a minha opinião sobre isto;

Eu participei de um fórum e diferente dos sites da SE (aonde o foco não é o debate) nestes fóruns aconteciam coisas como:

- Aparecia muita pergunta repetidas
- Usuários que achavam que moderadores serviam para responder as dúvidas
- Conteúdo de qualidade ia para o limbo
- Gerava brigas

*(vou aumentar esta lista, é que faz um ano que não acesso fóruns)*

O StackOverflow fez exatamente o que as pessoas mais interessadas em colaborar com conteúdo de qualidade, ele nos deu um *foco*.

Agora se começar a ter sala de tudo, eu acho que podemos perder muitas perguntas boas, ou até perder o foco da nossa comunidade e atrair só quem quer parasitar e passaremos a ter as características de "fóruns".

(Quando digo parasita, não quero dizer usuários novos, quero dizer apenas *alguns usuários novos*)

Tá, vocês podem até me criticar, sobre eu julgar alguns como parasitas, mas eu acho que um parasita pode mudar seus hábitos sim, só que a escolha é dele e por mais que façamos algo, como "abrir salas" para eles se sentirem mais confortáveis, isto não vai mudar o pensamento de ninguém.

Ok, então o motivo não é atrair novos usuários? É apenas para discutir a linguagem. Ótimo, ainda sim acho que muitas respostas de qualidade podem ficar no limbo destes chats e a comunidade vai perder.

Eu acho que chat é apenas para "discutir outros assuntos" ou "compreender melhor uma postagem".

*Isto é apenas a minha opinião*, concordo que se a comunidade achar bom então não irei mais falar disto e irei apoiar :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Nova sala de chat - JavaScript](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4032/3117) e [Nova Sala de Chat - C#, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, EF, etc](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4054/3117)

Comment: Concordo com todos aqui, ou seja, é daquelas situações em que todo mundo tá certo :) Ótima discussão.

Comment: Alem destas foi criado a sala http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24595/cafe-em-codigos para java

Comment: E também http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24221/arduino para debater a criação de um site sobre arduino até que se possa criar novos sites em português.

Comment: @Delfino Não foi incluído este chat, pois o proposito parece sobre criar um site/comunidade para o mesmo. Diferente dos demais que o foco "exclusivo" é discutir a linguagem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu não discordaria muito do que você disse, não fosse o fato de que nenhuma das duas salas (e, imagino, nenhuma das salas criadas no futuro) foi criada com o intuito de substituir o site:

[JavaScript](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4032/12):

> Não para criar uma sala como o Estouro de Pilha para um subgrupo mas sim uma sala mais focada em trocar experiência sobre a linguagem em foco e sem divagar demais no "bate-papo" e foco das conversas. Esta sala não deve servir para como regra tirar dúvidas que deviam ser perguntas úteis para a comunidade, mas sim como um complemento.

[C#](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4054/12):

> A ideia da sala é deixar a coisa um pouco mais dinâmica e prática. O objetivo é uma troca mais direcionada de informações, com links para exemplos, compartilhamento de GitHub, e assim por diante. Um verdadeiro Coding Craft, se é que se pode chamar assim.

Ambas deixam bem claro que tentam ser complementares ao site, como um lugar onde pessoas que praticam aquelas linguagens poderem conversar a respeito delas abertamente.

Além disso, não é a ausência de uma sala de chat nova que vai fazer um usuário novo *magicamente* fazer ótimas perguntas no site. Acredito justamente no contrário, que um ambiente aberto onde pessoas mais experiêntes podem guiar os novatos e incentivá-los a fazer suas perguntas no site, é incrivelmente benéfico à comunidade.

Comment: Obrigado Gabe, mas eu não disse que o intuito deles foi de substituir, o que eu quis dizer é que os usuários novos acabam usando mais lá e o processo de "substituir" é algo que meio automático e pessoal de cada um. Em outras palavras, algumas pessoas vão preferir usar os chats e a comunidade vai ficar dividida.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como eu disse, os chats só se tornaram "substitutos" para o site se as pessoas no chat permitirem isso. Não é o que acontece no Estouro de Pilha, por exemplo. Diversas pessoas chegam lá com dúvidas mas são orientadas a usar o site.

Comment: Entendi sim agora Gabe, mas ainda tenho motivos para pensar que o controle é mais difícil nestes tipos de abordagem, eu não sei se consigo me expressar. Talvez seja pessimismo meu :) Vou refletir... Obrigado por enquanto

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu entendo o seu pessimismo, mas por que não pagar pra ver? Fique tranquilo que nós moderadores iremos intervir se essas salas de chat estiverem prejudicando o site. E tenho certeza de que os próprios usuários que criaram as salas não querem ver o site prejudicado, e vão agir caso percebam isso acontecendo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Cara você conseguiu me deixar tranquilo, não tinha pensado assim.

Answer (score 9):

Eu não consigo ver as salas dessa forma, principalmente porque pra pessoa achar a sala ela precisa ter passado pelo *ptSO* primeiro e muitas nem sabem que existem o chat. (Além de ter a pontuação mínima de 20 pontos)

Como você mesmo disse o StackOverflow em si da foco nessa parte de ter respostas mais elaboradas, com qualidade e definitivas. A ideia das salas é pra sair desse clima competitivo, é pra ser um lugar onde você pode compartilhar e falar algo sem medo de alguém vir falando "não responde a pergunta", "não responda com links" ou "não funciona".

Eu até entendo seu receio com parasitas, mas se for pra pensar assim era melhor nem ter criado um *ptSO* porque "brasileiro é tudo folgado e quer as coisas prontos". As coisas não funcionam assim, se aparecer um parasita ele vai se retirar com o tempo, aqui não somos crianças, se a pessoa estiver abusando da nossa boa vontade ela vai tomar a lapada ou ignorada que merece.

Comment: Concordo com boa parte, exceto "mas se for pra pensar assim era melhor nem ter criado um ptSO" - O sistema do ptSO foi criado baseado em regras pré-determinadas e dá a capacidade de usuários normais poderem atuar como moderadores informais, fazendo assim as regras serem cumpridas com melhor eficiência. Eu não tenho medo dos parasitas, eu tenho medo de quem os alimentam - espero que não me leve a mal :)

Comment: Jogos online possuem regras/condutas e nem por isso todo mundo (incluindo os brasileiros) seguem a risco e/ou ligam pra isso :) ahahah

Comment: eu não vou explicar muito mais, porque acho que só seria possível entender a diferença de um sistema semi-automatizado (que é o ptSO) para um fórum convencional se você tive-se atuado como moderador em um destes fóruns, o clima era tão dificil e tudo estava tão descontrolado que houve migração em massa para o ptSO. Eu não vou mencionar o fórum que atuei, mas lhe digo que até usuários que viraram adm (cargo mais alto no fórum) perderam o controle e a razão devido ao formato e sem sombra de duvidas o ptSO é bem regrado e controlado.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que aqui vai servir bem pra explicar a motivação de eu ter feito a sala de chat não apenas de C#, mas de ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, Razor, Entity Framework, etc, etc, etc.

Como se pode ver, as tecnologias são combinadas. Grande parte das perguntas envolve normalmente 3 tags ou mais. Se fosse apenas para C# eu nem criaria a sala, mas montar um site utilizando as tecnologias envolvidas é mais complexo. Envolve configuração, boas práticas, estudar algum material específico, e assim por diante.

Quando alguém que não mexe com a tecnologia abre uma pergunta, acontece de o autor da pergunta, em vários casos, usar uma visão não-MVC em cima de uma aplicação MVC, aplicar um tutorial errado e vir pedir ajuda, teimar em usar uma coisa fora do padrão alegando "que está no padrão", e por aí vai. Vou listar os clichês mais recorrentes e comentar sobre eles:

> "Fiz uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC, configurei para MySQL mas não funcionou."

Diversos problemas aqui.

A aplicação ASP.NET MVC vem configurada por padrão com Microsoft SQL Server LocalDb, que é uma variação do SQL Server que não precisa de instalação. Trocar pra MySQL "porque acho melhor" é um problema terrível. As pessoas pescam tutoriais de internet, de YouTube, e vêm pra cá quando não funciona. O correto seria pelo menos fazer o tutorial até o fim, pra então trocar o provedor de acesso a dados seguindo um passo-a-passo. Se quiser usar MySQL, ok, mas há uma cadência de aprendizado que deveria ser seguida.

O melhor é terminar com "mas não funcionou". A turma pensa que a gente tem bola de cristal ou que consegue ver o que tá aparecendo na tela deles.

> "Estava implementando minha camada de repositório em cima do Entity Framework, mas estou com o seguinte problema: ".

Este é bem comum e me irrita bastante, sobretudo porque [vejam quantas vezes já precisei explicar que o Entity Framework já implementa um repositório, e o quanto esse tipo de esforço é inútil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio). O pior é que o autor da pergunta joga aquele super argumento: "Fulano que é MVP falou pra fazer assim", ou fica teimando porque quer que quer usar o padrão repositório pra aplicação dele ficar "super segura, elegante e padronizada".

Está **errado**. Ponto. Se estivesse certo, ele teria colocado uma versão completa do ponto de vista dele. Ainda assim, a chance de ser algo prolixo e inútil é bem grande.

Fora de brincadeira: já levei **meses** conversando com alguns aqui pra convencer que tá errado usar certas coisas que são tidas como consensos inquebráveis de práticas de programação, e que são completamente erradas.

> "Sou iniciante, estou tentando fazer um sistema assim, assim e assado. Não faço a menor ideia do que usar ou como fazer. Podem me ajudar?"

Esta pergunta, a meu ver, é boa. O site não concorda. Normalmente uma pergunta dessas é apontada como fora de escopo, ampla demais ou baseada em opiniões. Os bons samaritanos votam pra fechar, a pergunta é fechada, o autor da pergunta fica puto e sai falando cobras e lagartos do site.

Acho que não ter um ponto de partida e pedir ajuda é saudável. O site tem um espírito intransigente com esse tipo de pergunta, principalmente com tipos de respostas que as pessoas devolvem: "Pesquisa no Google", "Vá atrás de tutoriais", "Veja no site da Microsoft". Isto é **péssimo**. Como usuário novato, eu ficaria triste com comentários assim. Não foi com esse objetivo que procurei o site. Foi com o objetivo de conseguir uma informação de gente mais gabaritada que eu.

O chat é pra isso. Pra coisas que não cabem em perguntas. Pra não ter que abrir uma sala cada vez que alguém tem dúvida e a pergunta/resposta acaba tendo 50 comentários. O *transcript* cumpre bem a função de histórico. Centralizar a informação. Reunir as pessoas. Trocar informações rapidamente.

Acho pertinente criticar a motivação. Acredito que agora os motivos estejam um pouco melhor expostos.

Comment: Sobre seu mini-rant off-topic: essas perguntas não necessariamente são ruins e precisam ser fechadas. Se elas forem redigidas de modo a permitir respostas que dêem um passo-a-passo de como fazer, acho boas. O problema são as que geram opiniões rasas e só isso, ou aquelas cuja resposta necessariamente daria um livro (exagerando, algo do tipo "comecei a aprender programação ontem, como fazer um kernel pra linux?").

Comment: @bfavaretto Então, aí neste caso tem todo um processo que é feito pra melhorar a pergunta. Já salvei bastante pergunta das tags desta sala de chat. Já as perguntas insalváveis eu acho que tem que fechar mesmo, mas tem muitas outras também que com o empurrão correto ajudam horrores os autores das perguntas.